# OnTriggerEnter saying object is Untagged when it has the Tag Grass

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a sort of footstep sounds that check what tag the object has and based off of its tag it will play a certain sound.

I have my grass Tagged with "Grass" and the script says it is Untagged. Any ideas as to why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HitSounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int WaitTime;
    public AudioSource AUDIO;
    public AudioClip CLIP;

    // Wait thing for if I need it
    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Collision)
    {
        Debug.Log(Collision.gameObject.tag);
        Debug.Log(Collision.gameObject.tag.ToString());
        if (Collision.gameObject.tag.ToString() == "Grass")
        {
            AUDIO.PlayOneShot(CLIP, 1);
            Debug.Log("Playing");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the grass is tagged as isTrigger? Sure it’s Grass not grass or a grass layer or…..

Answer (score 0):

How is your game made?
How many colliders are there, especially in the moving object?
The collider is likely returning another object: not the grass collider.
To understand this, try to write this, and see what appears when you walk on the grass:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Collision)
{
    Debug.Log(Collision.gameObject.name);
}
```

If I helped you find your problem, you can thank me by accepting my answer :)

Comment: Hey thanks I did other things it was colliding with, but whenever it collides with the ground (grass) it doesn't even debug anything at all as if it hadn't just collided with "Grass"

Comment: Ah ok, if that's the problem, it probably means the weed doesn't have a tru triggered collider.
Grass is probably a solid collider to walk on and therefore you have no trigger enabled.
To solve, either add another collider to the grass by making it stick out a bit with trigger active, or add the same code to your code only with OnCollisionEnter.

Comment: vuoto pubblico OnTriggerEnter(Collision Collision) { Debug.Log(Collision.gameObject.name + “ | “ + Collision.gameObject.tag); }

Comment: Try this and say if it works

Comment: I will do that in a sec but the foot or thing that hits the floor is set to IsTrigger does the floor also need to be IsTriggee?

Comment: If the foot is set to isTirgger, the floor can be solid. I was thinking of another situation. Have you changed the layers in the "Project Settings> Physics" panel? It works with other objects. What is different about the floor from the others? Is the script on the gameObject with the trigger collider?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, it will answer that and many other questions you may have about triggers.  [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

Comment: I think that the layers on the objects may be different othe than that I don't really think so. What differences would cause issues?

Comment: If I understand your comment: if all objects have the "Default" layer and you haven't changed the settings in the "Physics" panel, they shouldn't have any difference. You can use layers to decide which objects to collide and which not, but if you haven't changed that panel, it means that all layers can collide.